# Достигнут максимальный уровень вложенности функции

Tags: php

Столкнулся с ошибкой: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!

Полазив в сети, нашел, что можно увеличить этот лимит `xdebug.max_nesting_level`. Но проблема в том, что `xdebug` не стоит и я в принципе в нем не нуждаюсь.

Функция вызывающая ошибку:

```
function tuples(array $arr, array &$res, array $prefix = [], $offset = 0) {
  for ($i = $offset; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $nextPrfx = array_merge($prefix, [$arr[$i]]);
    array_push($res, $nextPrfx);
    tuples($arr, $res, $nextPrfx, ++$offset);
  }
}
```

Массив, который передается в функцию может достигать 1000 значений

[Она выводит все возможные комбинации без повторов.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/97588b20bd0e6754ed099349ce1cd376a1334bc2)

Как избежать эту ошибку?

Может я не в ту сторону пошел.

Зачем это все нужно?

На сайте есть категории, у категорий есть характеристики.
При выборе любой из характеристик, нужно пройтись по всем характеристикам, чтобы отключить чекбоксы тем характеристикам, у которых нет товара

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Выбрали `Кредит`, мы проверяем - есть ли товар с выбранной характеристикой `Кредит` и `Безналичный расчет` - есть, оставляем чекбокс. Есть `Кредит` и `Наличный расчет` - товара нет, прячем чекбокс и так проходимся по всем характеристикам. - Это я сделал + я все полученную информацию кэширую на час.

В категориях где характеристик под 1000 - первая загрузка все этой информации занимает очень продолжительное время, после кежирования это происходит в считанные секунды.

Возникла идея, кэшировать все значения характеристик до нажатия пользователем, а для этого их нужно все перебрать и проверить по комбинация есть ли товар.

Как выглядит ~1000 характеристик(Таких блоков несколько)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы прикинули сколько будет этих комбинаций?

Comment: @teran Нет, мне даже страшно представить сколько их будет

Comment: а какую задачу вы вобще решаете? я так понимаю, что ваш пример генерит все сочетания из N разной длины. и если число сочетаний длины `k` определяется как `C^k_1000` то у вас получится сумма этого ряда для `k=1..N`, и эксель подсказывает что это `1,0715e301`. Даже если учесть, что вам каким то образом хватит времени их сгенерить, то что вообще можно с ними делать?

Comment: @teran `...Даже если учесть, что вам каким то образом хватит времени их сгенерить, то...`... то не хватит памяти)

Comment: @Manitikyl в примере кода они не хранятся ;)

Comment: @teran Дополнил вопрос, постарался объяснить суть, зачем это нужно

Comment: а зачем загружать их все сразу? показать вы их одновременно все равно не можете

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Я хочу закэшировать все возможные комбинации характеристик, что бы при выборе любой из комбинаций характеристик, информация бралась из кэша

Comment: вы эту тысячу характеристик сразу пользователю показываете? у него глаза не разбегаются случаем?

Comment: @teran Сразу, я честно не знаю, разбегаются или нет. Обновил вопрос, привел пример как +- выглядит 1000 характеристик

Comment: @nicolaa я тоже к тому что на экран 1000 значений не влезет, я предлагаю загружать страницами, прогрессивно или suggest, как например с размерами

Comment: @nicolaa еще механизм как с метками на этом ресурсе

Comment: @teran, что-то расчёты слишком сложные. Каждый элемент множества - 1 бит, он присутствует или отсутствует в данном множестве. Итого всего 2^N вариантов.

Comment: @vp_arth да, число сочетаний 2^N.  там уже при k=2  уже очень большое число вариантов получается, тем более чтобы говорить о каких либо переборах вообще всех

Comment: (не относящийся к вопросу комментарий): Вы бы хоть эти списки как-нибудь отсортировали, а то искать среди тысячи элементов, идущих в рандомном порядке, нужный, чтобы поставить галочку - это удовольствие для редких ценителей.